# How to make sure workflow in salesforce does not fire of there are no records in the email template/

Tags: email, salesforce, workflow

I have a requirement to send an email to a group of people. However I do not want to send any mail if there are no records matching my criteria. Currently I am using Time based workflow to send the emails. But the problem is it sends an email with zero records as well. I want to make the workflow intelligent enough. I am looking for some option which uses configuration and not programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used 2 workflow rules to achieve this requirement.
1. Time-Dependent WF Rule to update certain fields in contact which will be used to save the run time for the next email.
2. WF Rule with immediate actions which read a particular field value updated by the Time-Dependent WF Rule for a certain contact and triggers an Email Alert picking the Case Template.
I also use the Update event on the Contact Trigger to update the check box on Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Have a roll up summary that counts total of top priority cases.

Use that roll-up summary field in your workflow entry criteria.

Comment: there is no master child relationship between the object on which wf rule is written and Case object.

Comment: I guess the should be related in some way. You can use declarative roll ups for lookups: https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries